# help in Solving PDE heat problem with FFCT

Tags: heat-equation

solve the following heat problem using Finite Fourier Coseine Transform(FFCT):
 A metal bar of length $L$, is at constant temperature of $U0$, at $t=0$ the end $x=L$ is suddenly given the constant temperature of $U_1$ and the end $x=0$ is insulated. Assuming that the surface of the bar is insulated, find the temperature at any point $x$ of the bar at any time $t>0$ , assume $k=1$

Equations used:
 1. Heat equation: $$ \frac {\partial^2 u} {\partial x^2}  = \frac 1 k   \frac {\partial u} {\partial t} $$
 2. the following FFCT Equations ( as in the attached pic):
 [FFCT Equations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p7zAB.jpg)

My attempt at solutions goes like this:
$$ \frac {\partial^2 u} {\partial x^2}  = \frac 1 k   \frac {\partial u} {\partial t} $$
$$ \mathcal{F}_{fc}  \left[ \frac {\partial u} {\partial t} \right] =  \mathcal{F}_{fc}  \frac {\partial^2 u} {\partial x^2} $$
$$ \frac {dU} {dt} =  {-\left( \frac {{n} {\pi}} L  \right)}ˆ{2}  *  F(x,t) +  \left(  {-1} \right)ˆn  \frac {\partial{f(L,t)}} {\partial x} - \frac {\partial{f(0,t)}} {\partial x} $$
$$ \frac {dU} {dt} = -  \left( \frac {{n} {\pi}} L  \right)ˆ(2) *   F(x,t) +  \left(  {-1} \right)ˆn  \frac {\partial{f(L,t)}} {\partial x} $$

and i don't know how to continue, can you provide the rest of the solution in details please,
regards.

Comment: Hello Mr. @Harry49 , here is my complete problem.

Comment: i just want to make sure you got the problem @Harry49

Comment: Hello Mr Harry @Harry49

Comment: Please stop the spam! The most straightforward way to solve this PDE problem is separation of variables (see e.g. [[1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2137327/pde-1d-heat-diffusion-problem)]).

Comment: dear Mr. @Harry49 , i already solve it using separation of variables, but am required solve it using the Finite Fourier Cosine Transform (FFCT), and i tried but stopped somewhere.

Comment: can you spot where my mistake ? @Harry49

Comment: any updates mr @Harry49